# How to hide .env passwords in Laravel whoops output?

Tags: php, laravel, environment-variables, secret-key, whoops

How can I hide my passwords and other sensitive environment variables on-screen in Laravel's whoops output?

Sometimes other people are looking at my development work. I don't want them to see these secrets if an exception is thrown, but I also don't want to have to keep toggling debug on and off, or spin up a dedicated site just for a quick preview.

[image: whoops output screenshot with passwords shown]

Answer (score 112, accepted):

As of [Laravel 5.5.13](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/21336), you can censor variables by listing them under the key `debug_blacklist` in `config/app.php`. When an exception is thrown, whoops will mask these values with asterisks `*` for each character.

For example, given this `config/app.php`

```
return [

    // ...

    'debug_blacklist' => [
        '_ENV' => [
            'APP_KEY',
            'DB_PASSWORD',
            'REDIS_PASSWORD',
            'MAIL_PASSWORD',
            'PUSHER_APP_KEY',
            'PUSHER_APP_SECRET',
        ],
        '_SERVER' => [
            'APP_KEY',
            'DB_PASSWORD',
            'REDIS_PASSWORD',
            'MAIL_PASSWORD',
            'PUSHER_APP_KEY',
            'PUSHER_APP_SECRET',
        ],
        '_POST' => [
            'password',
        ],
    ],
];
```

Results in this output:

[image: whoops exception page]

Comment: it might be usefull to make a pull request for the laravel docs

Comment: @JeffPuckett Ah, you're right, I mistakenly thought that .13 is lower than .4  as you would with decimal places

Comment: Is there any reason that this won't work in Laravel 5.7? I found `registerBlacklist` inside of the WhoosHander under Laravels Foundations but as best as I can tell it is not used.

Answer (score 80):

First of all, love the solution by Jeff above.

2nd, if like me you wanna hide all the `env variables` while still use whoops, here is a solution:

```
'debug_blacklist' => [
        '_COOKIE' => array_keys($_COOKIE),
        '_SERVER' => array_keys($_SERVER),
        '_ENV' => array_keys($_ENV),        
    ],
```

**Output:**

[image]

**EDIT:**
Legend has it that since laravel 7x you would need `debug_hide` key instead

Comment: Thanks for this. I am still confused why people would want all env variables printed on screen with every error.

Comment: exactly man.. may be say 10% would want it.. but NOT 90% of the laravel devs!

Comment: Hear hear! I accidentally exposed my mailgun api key a few months back which resulted in over 1200 phishing emails coming through my account. Horrific! If I ever need to see what is in my env I do it the oldschool way by opening the damn thing!

Comment: exactly!! If I need to know my env, I would just open the env file and NOT have the env exposed by accident on a page Ive no idea for a week or so

Comment: Thank you. Great answer.

Comment: I'm not sure this works if you use Laravel's config:cache and your environment variables change (like the "physical" ones set by the environment, not the .env file)

Comment: thank you, it's just what I was looking for, hide all

Comment: I came here after I saw a laravel site exploding on my face showing all the password and DB name. A framework has to be dumbproof to a certain level. I dont know that guy but i no his DB name password admin email and password.

Comment: @warmwhisky This is certainly not a feature. I dont know PHP but any such thing is available in debug mode only and production never splashes your info around

Comment: Thank you for this! Exposing those variables by default is so risky. I get you don't want APP_DEBUG=true on any public facing server but it is such an easy mistake. If anything the variables should be hidden by default and there should be a whitelist

Answer (score 12):

Thanks Jeff and Raheel for helping out, but I just found a little gotcha:

Even if I clear out all environment keys from `_ENV`, the same keys are STILL exposed through the `_SERVER` variables listed.

Adding the code below in `config/app.php` would hide all environment variables from the whoops page:

```
'debug_blacklist' => [
        '_SERVER' => array_keys($_ENV),
        '_ENV' => array_keys($_ENV),        
],
```

Comment: And how is this different from Raheel answer, besides less the cookie line in your code ? Or has he edited his answer after yours ?

Comment: There is a subtle but significant difference between '_SERVER' => array_keys($_SERVER) and '_SERVER' => array_keys($_ENV).

Answer (score 8):

I've made a [package](https://github.com/GlaivePro/Hidevara) to solve this problem.

Just install it using

```
composer require glaivepro/hidevara
```

Most of the server and all the env variables will be removed. Any password-like fields in `$_POST` will have their values hidden.

You can also customize it in either blacklist or whitelist approach to show/obfuscate/remove fields however you like.

Answer (score 8):

The solution by @jeff + @raheel is great!!! On a project recently we found we sometimes wanted to whitelist a property or two, so building on the above, you can whitelist specific properties you want to debug with something like:

```
'debug_blacklist' => [
    '_COOKIE' => array_diff(array_keys($_COOKIE), array()),
    '_SERVER' => array_diff(array_keys($_SERVER), array('APP_URL', 'QUERY_STRING')),
    '_ENV' => array_diff(array_keys($_ENV), array()),
],
```

If you want to allow that list to be configured via .env, you can do something like:

```
'debug_blacklist' => [
    '_COOKIE' => array_diff(
        array_keys($_COOKIE),
        explode(",", env('DEBUG_COOKIE_WHITELIST', ""))
    ),
    '_SERVER' => array_diff(
        array_keys($_SERVER),
        explode(",", env('DEBUG_SERVER_WHITELIST', ""))
    ),
    '_ENV' => array_diff(
        array_keys($_ENV),
        explode(",", env('DEBUG_ENV_WHITELIST', ""))
    ),
],
```

Then in your .env, do something like:

```
DEBUG_SERVER_WHITELIST="APP_URL,QUERY_STRING"
```

Cheers!

Comment: I'd just like to mention that this can be added in `app.php`

Answer (score 6):

Usually for local development, we should set the **APP_DEBUG** environment variable to **true**. So that we can have better insights of the debugging error and warnings.

But in the production environment, this value should always be **false**. If the value is set to **true** in production, you risk exposing sensitive env passwords to your application’s end users.

As of Laravel 5.5.x also provides a **solution** for it.

You just need to add the `debug_blacklist` option in your `config/app.php` configuration file. After adding this option, Laravel will **blacklist** all the keys mentioned in `debug_blacklist` option with asterisk.

You can use it with two ways:

### Method 1 – Blacklist selective ENV keys and passwords

```
return [
    // ...
    'debug_blacklist' => [
        '_ENV' => [
            'APP_KEY',
            'DB_PASSWORD',
        ],
        '_SERVER' => [
            'APP_KEY',
            'DB_PASSWORD',
        ],
        '_POST' => [
            'password',
        ],
    ],
];
```

### Method 2 – Blacklist all the ENV keys and passwords

```
return [
 // ...
'debug_blacklist' => [
  '_COOKIE' => array_keys($_COOKIE),
  '_SERVER' => array_keys($_SERVER),
  '_ENV' => array_keys($_ENV),
  ],
]
```

Reference Taken From : https://techjeni.com/how-to-secure-and-hide-env-passwords-from-laravel-debug-output/

Answer (score 4):

Laravel 5.6 not works for my.
but this works:

```
$envKeys = [];
$serverKeys = [];
$cookieKeys = [];
foreach ( $_ENV as $key => $value ) { if(is_string($value)) $envKeys[] = $key; }
foreach ( $_SERVER as $key => $value ) { if(is_string($value)) $serverKeys[] = $key; }
foreach ( $_COOKIE as $key => $value ) { if(is_string($value)) $cookieKeys[] = $key; }

return [

    // ...

    'debug_blacklist' => [
        '_COOKIE'   => $cookieKeys,
        '_SERVER'   => $serverKeys,
        '_ENV'      => $envKeys,
    ],
];
```

I would be grateful for a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Just Change

```
APP_DEBUG=true
```

To:

```
APP_DEBUG=false
```

In the .env file.

Comment: yeah in production great, but the question states I'm in development, and so I would like all the other niceties afforded by whoops in this environment

Answer (score 0):

For Laravel 5.6-5.8:

```
'debug_blacklist' => [
    '_COOKIE'   => array_keys(array_filter($_COOKIE, function($value) {return is_string($value);})),
    '_SERVER'   => array_keys(array_filter($_SERVER, function($value) {return is_string($value);})),
    '_ENV'      => array_keys(array_filter($_ENV, function($value) {return is_string($value);})),
],
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing this issue in production environment, Laravel 5.7
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/configuration

Here 3 ways we can reslove this issue.

***config/app.php*** file add below line of code

**TIPS #1:** Block List for all variable

```
'debug_blacklist' => [
    '_COOKIE' => array_keys($_COOKIE),
    '_SERVER' => array_keys($_SERVER),
    '_ENV' => array_keys($_ENV),        
],
```

**TIPS #2:** Block List for specific varaibles (Best Practice)

```
return [

    // ...
    '_ENV' => [
          'APP_KEY',
          'DB_PASSWORD',
          'REDIS_PASSWORD',
          'MAIL_PASSWORD',
          'PUSHER_APP_KEY',
          'PUSHER_APP_SECRET',
          'AWS_APP_SECRET',
          'S3_BUCKET_SECRET',
          'SOCKET_APP_SECRET',
          'TWILIO_APP_SECRET',
     ],
     '_SERVER' => [
          'APP_KEY',
          'DB_PASSWORD',
      ],
      '_POST' => [
          'password',
      ],
 ]
```

**TIPS #3:** Debug variable

APP_DEBUG=true to APP_DEBUG=false

**NOTE:**

> Production enviroment keep always Debug False

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of great answers here (credits to @Jeff and @Raheel and @Benjamin and everyone else), but I would like to have a bit more flexible and universal solution. I extended this snippet intended for the **config/app.php** file even further:

```
$debug_blacklist=array();
if(env("DEBUG_VAR_LISTING")!==null)
    foreach(explode(",", env("DEBUG_VAR_LISTING", "")) as $i){
        global ${"_{$i}"};
        if(env("DEBUG_VAR_BLACKLIST_{$i}")!==null)
            $debug_blacklist["_{$i}"]=explode(",", env("DEBUG_VAR_BLACKLIST_{$i}", ""));
        elseif(env("DEBUG_VAR_WHITELIST_{$i}")!==null)
            $debug_blacklist["_{$i}"]=array_diff(
                array_keys(${"_{$i}"}),
                explode(",", env("DEBUG_VAR_WHITELIST_{$i}", ""))
            );
    }

return [
    'debug_blacklist' => $debug_blacklist,
];
```

Then you can blacklist and whitelist directly in **.env** and only if and what you need.

So if you don't really need anything from **$_ENV** you can block all variables and for example just passwords in **$_POST**, but show `APP_URL` and `QUERY_STRING` from **$_SERVER**:

```
DEBUG_VAR_LISTING="SERVER,ENV,POST,COOKIE"
DEBUG_VAR_WHITELIST_SERVER="APP_URL,QUERY_STRING"
DEBUG_VAR_WHITELIST_ENV=""
DEBUG_VAR_BLACKLIST_POST="password"
```

Answer (score -1):

I struggled with this too for a bit on a dev machine. my solution was to edit `vendor/filp/whoops/src/Whoops/Handler/PrettyPageHandler.php` and add in:

```
public function sanitizePrivate($data, $badwords){
    foreach ($data as $key=>$value) {
       
        foreach ($badwords as $keyword) {
               // dd($key);
            if (strpos(strtolower($key), $keyword) !== FALSE) {
                $data[$key] = "***************";
            }
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

This converts all the incoming data to lowercase and then searches for partial matches so you don't have to specify every variation of password variable names. Then in the `handle()` function, define terms you want to exclude.

```
$badwords = array("password", "pwd", "secret", "key", "token", "salt", "mail");
$_SERVER=$this->sanitizePrivate($_SERVER, $badwords);
$_ENV=$this->sanitizePrivate($_ENV, $badwords);
```

Comment: thanks for sharing! however I would really rather not modify a vendor file because it increases complexity when upgrading. you could fix that by making a PR to the source library. also the partial matching seems too loose, like in your example we'd lose attributes like `email` or `donkey` which might be unexpected or unwanted, but maybe it's ok.