# Why is the information on Laravel's error screen hidden?

Tags: php, laravel

I took over a Laravel 5.5 project, and there is something going on that I have never encountered - the content on the error reporting screen is all replaced by stars.

[image]

I don't know what the previous devs did to accomplish this, but obviously I want to be able to see this info. The .env content seems fairly obvious:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_HOST=http://localhost
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_TESTMODE=false
APP_CACHE_ENABLED=true
```

Other than that, there are API keys for Stripe, AWS etc, but nothing that would presume to block me from viewing the info on the error screen.

Why is this problem occurring and how can I fix it?

Comment: `APP_TESTMODE` seems unusual, I would check where that leads. You may want to check as well your composer.json for any unusual package

Comment: Yeah, @ChristopheHubert, I think so too

Comment: @ChristopheHubert I've tried changing or removing `APP_TESTMODE`, had no effect. Also found its usage in the code, it's definitely unrelated.

Comment: does that answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46407010/4258328

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have the `debug_blacklist` set, as seen in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/configuration#hiding-environment-variables-from-debug)

Simply remove the `debug_blacklist` array from your config/app.php configuration file and the values will reveal.

Comment: Yep, this is it. They have: `'debug_blacklist' => [
  '_SERVER' => array_keys($_SERVER),
  '_ENV' => array_keys($_ENV),
 ],` so it's all hidden for that reason. Why someone would hide all this info is a different question :)

Comment: If you want other people to see your work on a live server with debug on - it is good to hide sensitive data - especially Stripe Key 

Comment: I suppose, but it seems kinda indiscriminate to just hide everything else in the process :)

Comment: Agreed, this seems like overkill, but I guess it made sense for the previous guys 