# Laravel Lumen .env variable values are showing when I dump Request

Tags: laravel, lumen

I'm noticing when I `dd($request)` from the `Illuminate\Http\Request`, I see all of my `.env` variables and values. This is a security risk that I'm not aware how to hide. How would I store these values in `.env` but not make them publicly assessable like this?

Comment: `dump()` and `dd()` should be only used for development purposes.

Comment: Define production environment APP_ENV in .env.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comment, you should not use `dd()` nor `dump()` in production.

If you are concerned about seeing env variables being displayed in your application, you can either

1. set `APP_DEBUG=false` in your `.env` file
2. set the `'debug_blacklist'` key in your `app\config` file to hide some specific keys from the `Whoops` page (As seen on https://stackoverflow.com/a/46407010/4258328 )